# Gnome boxes wont load Ubuntu 23.04

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization, 23.04, gnome-boxes

I am recently shifted from KDE neon to Ubuntu 23.04. I am running clean ubuntu, without any dualbooting. I have installed my windows OS on gnome boxes, sometime after reboot gnome boxes are not loading.

```
    My system details:
    
    I am using ubuntu 23.04,
    Kernel version: 6.2.0-20-generic
    Gnome boxes installed from snap store.
```